# Any nextjs example where I need to use _document over _app

Tags: next.js

It seems I can do everything that I need to do in both `_app` and `_document` for my application just in `_app` like

```
// _app.tsx
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no"
        />
        <title>Payment</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Then when should I use `_document` **necessarily?** I found `_document` pointless because:

- I shouldn't place `viewport` `meta` tags in `_document` as nextjs compiler warnings about it. (I thought `_document` is a good place for markups in `head` because `_document` gets called only once on server-side and not on client-side) If I can't place everything of a kind like `head` markup in one place, I'd like to avoid using that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `_document` if you want to customize a page's `<html>` and `<body>` tags. For example...

Adding the global [`lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) attribute:

```html
<Html lang="en">
```

Adding custom styles:

```html
<body className="bg-white">
```

Answer (score 2):

_document is where you put third party links and scripts

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=optional"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

If you are using styled components you need to configure it in _document.jsx file.
https://github.com/massaaki/nextjs-with-styled-component/blob/main/src/pages/_document.tsx